# Python Flask transaction control in service layer

Tags: python, flask

I have a service method that calls two DAOs methods.
How can I control transaction in service layer with Flask?
Is there a annotation `@Transaction` like spring?

The following method `atualizarProvedorDaAgenda(self, agendaId, provedor)`
need to be transactional:

```
class AgendasService:
    agendasDao = None
    companhiaAereaDao = None
    diaSemanaDao = None
    playerDao = None
    canalDao = None
    provedorDao = None
    regrasDao = None
    entidadesRegrasDao = None

    def __init__(self, sqlserver):
        self.companhiaAereaDao = CompanhiaAereaDao(sqlserver)
        self.diaSemanaDao = DiaSemanaDao(sqlserver)
        self.playerDao = PlayerDao(sqlserver)
        self.canalDao = CanalDao(sqlserver, self.playerDao)
        self.provedorDao = ProvedorDao(sqlserver)
        self.tipoColetaDao = TipoColetaDao(sqlserver)
        self.agendasDao = AgendasDao(sqlserver, self.tipoColetaDao)
        self.regrasDao = RegrasDao(sqlserver)
        self.entidadesRegrasDao = EntidadesRegrasDao(sqlserver)

    def atualizarProvedorDaAgenda(self, agendaId, provedor):
        self.provedorDao.atualizarProvedorDaAgenda(agendaId, provedor)
        self.agendasDao.ativar(agendaId)
        return "provedor atualizado"
```

DAOs classes:

```
class ProvedorDao:
    server = None
    database = None
    username = None
    password = None
    driver = None

    def __init__(self, sqlserverDataConn):
        self.server = sqlserverDataConn['host']
        self.database = sqlserverDataConn['db']
        self.username = sqlserverDataConn['user']
        self.password = sqlserverDataConn['passwd']
        self.driver = sqlserverDataConn['driver']

    def getConn(self):
        return  pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + self.driver + ';SERVER=' + self.server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + self.database + ';UID=' + self.username + ';PWD=' + self.password)

    def atualizarProvedorDaAgenda(self, agendaId, provedor):
        query = "UPDATE T_CMP_RELAC_AGD_PROVD  SET CTL_PROVD=?,QTD_MAQUI=?, PCT_MAQUI=?, CTL_DISTR=?, STA_ATIVO=?, QTD_INSTA=?, DHR_ALTER=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOM_USU_ALTER=?  WHERE CTL_REL_AGD_PROVD = ? "
        dataQuery = (provedor['provedor']['provedorId'], provedor['qtdeMaquinas'], provedor['percentualMaquinas'], provedor['tipoDistribuicao']['tipoDistribuicaoId'], provedor['ativo'], provedor['qtdeInstancias'], provedor['nomUsuario'], provedor['id'])
        cnxn = self.getConn()
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, dataQuery)
        cnxn.commit()  





class AgendasDao:
    server = None
    database = None
    username = None
    password = None
    driver = None
    tipoColetaDao = None

    def __init__(self, sqlserverDataConn, tipoColetaDao):
        self.server = sqlserverDataConn['host']
        self.database = sqlserverDataConn['db']
        self.username = sqlserverDataConn['user']
        self.password = sqlserverDataConn['passwd']
        self.driver = sqlserverDataConn['driver']
        self.tipoColetaDao = tipoColetaDao

    def getConn(self):
        return  pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + self.driver + ';SERVER=' + self.server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + self.database + ';UID=' + self.username + ';PWD=' + self.password)



    

    def ativar(self, agendaId):
        query = "UPDATE T_CMP_AGENDA SET STA_ACTIV=1, DHR_ALTER=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOM_USU_ALTER=?  WHERE CTL_AGEND = ? "
        dataQuery = ('CRUD', agendaId)
        cnxn = self.getConn()
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, dataQuery)
        cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Comment: I need to know how to control transaction in service layer of flask python code

Comment: in the method   atualizarProvedorDaAgenda(self, agendaId, provedor) ,  how could I control transaction ?